# Magento 1 extension and composer : Packagist and/or Firegento

Tags: magento-1, extensions, composer

I just finished an extension and I was wondering : in order to have my extension available in composer, is it better to publish it on Packagist or in Firegento ?

In fact, I already published it to Packagist and it seems to work (my extension is loaded as expected), but then I found some sources like [this one](https://alanstorm.com/php_composer_magento_tutorial/) where it is said :

> For reasons we don’t have time to cover, having Magento packages as a part of packagist.org isn’t feasible. Instead, the crew over at Firegento, via their hackathon, have created their own custom composer repository at packages.firegento.com. This is a composer repository for Magento extensions.

For me, it's *feasible*, but I'm probably misunderstanding something ...

In other words, my question is : is it feasible to have a Magento extension on
Packagist and make it work with composer ? If not, why ?

For information, I use `aydin-hassan/magento-core-composer-installer` and `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` in my `composer.json`.

Thanks.

Comment: Good question! I thought the main purpose of the Firegento repository was to mirror Magento connect. The reasons are probably not of technical nature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packagist works fine. In fact it is only a catalog of modules, so technically it doesn't matter.

The reason you might want to publish it on our (packages.firegento.com) satis is, that somewhere™ (I can't find the source anymore) back in the days™ someone™ said, that it would be good to have a separate satis/packagist for software packages/modules/plugins which doesn't run without a certain software. In our case magento.

Packages on packagist.org are expected to run with PHP only.

Thanks @Flyingmana! Source for my claim: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own

Comment: the source is probably the composer documentation: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own